# Binary tree representation for XML file.

Tags: xml-parsing, binary-tree

Can anybody tell me how xml file can be represented in binary tree? Actually i am studying clish framework and found that here xml file is represented in binary tree when I searched for the same did not get answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for,but take a look at following link it will give you brief idea of how it is done [Implementation of the Tree Structure 
in the XML](http://proceedings.informingscience.org/InSITE2012/InSITE12p027-051Bulajic0009.pdf)